# Problem with Stripe credit card processing on IOS but works on Win and Android

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a website, https://www.trxaas.com
I use Stripe for credit card processing.  In particular I use "Use with Checkout".  The checkout process, to make a purchase, works just fine on Windows and Android.  But on IOS the checkout button shows up but does nothing.  Behaving like a dead click_event.  I called Stripe.  They don't know.

I am running on IIS 10.  The file is just plain HTML with the Stripe code pasted in.
The specific page giving trouble is 
https://www.trxaas.com/user_registration_catalog.html

In below link, I stripped out CSS and everything else to test with this bare bones page... still doesn't work on iPhone IOS.
https://www.trxaas.com/catalog.html

You can see the code by viewing code source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I look in the developer console, there's a warning about having loaded Stripe.js twice. I'd start there.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz    Did you observe Stripe.js loading twice on catalog.html or user_registration_catalog.html or both?  I am using Electric Mobile Studio for IOS testing.  When I go to catalog.html and look at the Console after clicking on "Checkout" then Console shows...    O 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined  
(anonymous function)  
(anonymous function)  
O GET httos://is.stripe.com/v3   
O 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null  
(anonymous function)  
(anonymous function)

Comment: Still can't get to work on iPhone (IOS).  Works fine on PC and Android.  I still see the error about 'Uncaught ReferenceError. Stripe is not defined'.  In catalog.html I stripped out everything.  I made sure I'm loading Stripe in header.  I made sure I'm using HTTPS.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: On https://www.trxaas.com/catalog.html I get `TypeError: checkoutButton is null`, because you try to use it in the `<head>` when the element doesn't exist yet. I'd encourage you to use the developer console to ensure there are no JS errors on your test pages.